# Why was Beca's riff-off considered invalid?

Tags: plot-explanation, pitch-perfect

In [Pitch Perfect](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1981677/), why was Beca's riff-off [considered invalid](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q573_hDhTbE)? What "it" did they need to match and how? I've watched this particular scene, like, 50 times and I still have no clue. Maybe there's something in the book that they forgot to include in the movie?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Jesse's song used the word "*it*" in its lyrics. Beca's rap riffed off this word. However, her song began with the word "*it's*" and was therefore deemed invalid on a technicality.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Yeah, unexpected rule :)

Comment: @coleopterist, Is there actually such a rule or did the movie just made that up?

Comment: But before that Jesse starts off "I guess it's just the woman in you..." after Stacy is singing "and I'll hold you tight" so wouldn't I'll/I break that same rule first?

Comment: @caitlyn I thought the same thing Caitlyn but The lyrics are: I'll make love to you
Like you want me to AND
I'll... I thought Jesse came in on "I guess that's just the woman in you..." but he actually started singing "AND I guess that's just the woman in you..." So Jesse cut Stacy off on the word "And" and started singing the word "And". Had he come in on the word "I'll" with "I", then they would be disqualified. What made it confusing is that Stacy actually got the words "And I'll" out making it seem like Jesse made a mistake. But if you re-watch the scene, you'll hear that Stacy and Jesse

Comment: It kinda _is_ the same word, though :)

Answer (score 4):

Jesse sang "it feels like the first time" and Beca's song started off with "it's going down...", deeming it invalid.

Answer (score 4):

Beca sang "**it's** going down," and not **it** from "it feels like the first time," therefore causing them to lose the competition.